# Codeigniter mysql db query to display 3 rows of results on page using 2 tables on 3 joins

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, api

New to codeigniter and having trouble on a query for 2 tables. The first table **"claims"** is loaded into a page showing 3 of the 15 or so cells in the headings (as per claims.png), a method in the second method is then called to load **site/claims/view_claim_det/$claim_id** when user clicks the "view claim" link. which the new view by **claim_id**.
The second table **driver_detail** has to load 2 rows (#1 is nonfault and #2 is atfault info ) through a query defined by *nonfault* **claims.claim_driver_id1 = driver_detail.driver_id** and *atfault* **claims.claim_driver_id2 = driver_detail.driver_id** (2 rows returned to display as per ClaimsDetail.png).

I have the **claims** table row loaded where the results fall mainly at the end of the page, I can't figure how to call the **driver_detail** table and run the 2 queries to then display the results required for each Nonfault and Atfault info.

I'm sure its something so easy, each time I think I have it I get plagued by php errors.

Any help would be amazing!!

[claims view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiRlf.png)

[claims_detail view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxNiA.png)

Comment: your query and your errors screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do in this case.
Create 2 methods, one for each view: atfault and nonfault that would return their own sections individually. Then..

1,.  You could use Ajax to display each sections separately.
2,   if you need to provide an initial view then you could call these methods within your main method and pass the rendered sections as a variable to your view.